# Defining custom bss section name with clang13 on windows

Tags: windows, clang

I'm trying to setup some variables in a custom memory section.
clang doesn't recognize:

```
#pragma section (".special") // gives a warning "unknown pragmas"
#pragma bss_seg (".special") // gives a warning "unknown pragmas"
#pragma section bss=".special" // no warning but is ignored in the object file.
```

I'm building with clang13 on windows with the target i686-pc-windows-gnu.

`__attribute__((used, section(".special")))`
is working but I would like to not specify this attribute for each variable.

Any suggestions?
Where can I get a list of all the supported pragmas for this specific platform?